# Is Process Builder available in Professional Edition?

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, professional-edition

I would like to know if Process Builder is available in Professional Edition, also, what happen if we attempt to install a managed package that contains Process Builder as dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lightning Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm) is even available in Professional Edition:

> Available in: both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience
>
> Available in: Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

While many of the other features for automation are not available in Professional Edition, they're finally giving Professional Edition users some ability to perform automation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is this something that I need to request to Support? because so far I couldn't find the "Process Builder" link in the Setup.

Comment: @Yucel I believe this is in Winter '17. Try signing up for a pre-release Lightning Professional org.

Comment: However there is a limit on the number of Processes in Professional to 5 active  ones - http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Comment: It appears the 5-process limit for PE is no longer in effect (the document in Dave's link above is from May 1, 2016).  The [Spring '17 docs](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/8/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) (see the bottom of pg 16) don't make a distinction between limits on # of processes in PE vs. other editions

Answer (score 2):

I might be responding to this question a bit Late but,

What sfdcFox said is correct however, I faced an issue with Professional edition while installing a package with ProicessBuilder. My Processbuilder has ACTION TYPE set to APEX because I am using a @future method to make API calls when the processBuilder is triggered. It resulted me to failing the installation as ACTION TYPE set to APEX are not compatible in Professional Edition. Please mind that and other ACTION TYPEs might work without any issues. Please go through the documentation depending on your requirement.