# How many flows (visual workflow) and process builder can be created in professional edition?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I looking for a documentation about  wheter is it possible to create flows in professional edition or not and if it's possible how many flows are the limit?

According what I found, it is only available in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_flow_limits.htm). But,  I have a professional instance and I can create flows:

[image: Probably I'm confused in terminology,]

Moreover, I've read there is a limit of 5 active process builder, but in my professional instance I can create more than that.

In the forum: [Is Process Builder available in Professional Edition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142141/is-process-builder-available-in-professional-edition) , someone concluded that it looks like since Spring 17, professional has the same limits of process builder as enterprise, Unlimited edition. Can someone help me clarifing this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Salesforce Features and Edition Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_general.htm&type=0) and other related documentation, release notes (like in [Winter ’16 Release Notes on Visual Workflow enhancements](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow.htm)) they are:

> Available in: **Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited**, and **Developer**
>   Editions

Even [Workflows can only be enabled for additional fee](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm):

> As a partner, workflows within your application run in a Professional
>   Edition org. However, customers can’t create their own workflows. **They
>   must purchase the feature directly from Salesforce.**

Many features in Salesforce can be a contractual limitations - menus are available in setup, however you are not allowed to use them according to your contract terms.

Comment: But, in my case, I can create several flows and more than 5 process builder, I dont understand why. Anyway, thank you for your answer, it's more clear for me.

Comment: 'Contractual limitations' means that the functionality can still be available for your org, but you are not allowed to use any of it and this is to what your client or company agreed to by signing contract with Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

As a customer, the first place you want to check is the [Edition comparison guide](https://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf)

Note that Workflows are not available for Professional Edition, however, the Documentation on Salesforce Limits Quick Reference Guide clearly states the following:

> In addition, this guide doesn’t include limits of: ...
>
> - Your Salesforce contract

as well as:

> Contractual limits may also apply, as per your Salesforce contract.

Workflows can be purchased as an addon, however, depending on costs, it might make more sense to simply upgrade to Enterprise edition.

fyi: There is an [Appexchange package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4NIeEAN) that provides Workflows for 125 USD a month. it also has a 14 day trial.

Furtheremore, there is an [IDEA](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrNv) which you can vote on to have it added to the Profesional Edition.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's clear for me. Anyway, I have in my organization available flows and I've created more that 5 process builder. Maybe they are paying those additional fetures and they don't know.